# connect to visual studio online 2013 from visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops

I can login to TFS ( now called visual studio online 2013 ) from my existing machine. Recently I got a new machine.  I am trying to connect from this machine for the first time. I get "Unable to connect to the remote server" error.  I think my port number may be incorrect.

What command can I issue on my working computer to know the correct port number used? ( I have tried 8080 already).

I am using "team" -> "connect to team foundation server" and then adding server.

Comment: You can use Visual Studio 2012. You can also use Visual Studio 2010, but you'll need to install Service Pack 1 and KB2662296 first. Or, you can use Visual Studio 2008 SP1, with this GDR update. Launch Visual Studio, then connect to Visual Studio Online using your account URL and select your team project.http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/connect-to-vs.aspx

Comment: Just an aside, TFS isn't now VSO. They are separate products.

Comment: Finally, Microsoft changed the name of Team Foundation Service to “Visual Studio Online”. The sentence is from  http://blog.discountasp.net/team-foundation-server-vs-visual-studio-online/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install [Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) (and don't forget to install SP1 first)
Then just specify your VSO account URL in the Connect dialog e.g. https://testaccount.visualstudio.com/
You don't need to add a port number, it should work without it

Comment: I was able to solve the problem following your directions (and Alex's too). This is accepted answer.